# Checking for jQuery using ASP.NET Bundling fails with IE8

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, internet-explorer-8, bundling-and-minification, jquery-2.0

I have a website using jQuery 2.0+ and would like to perform an action if jQuery hasn't been loaded. In essence, I'm checking for any browser that doesn't support jQuery 2, like IE8, 7, 6, etc.

I'm doing so like this in jquery.check.js

```
if (typeof window.jQuery == 'undefined') {
    //show not supported page
}
```

The BundleConfig is doing the bundling like this:

```
var b1 = new ScriptBundle("~/bundle/js").Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.check.js"
            );
        b1.Orderer = new InputBundleOrderer();
        b1.Transforms.Clear(); //this removes the mimification for debugging purposes

        bundles.Add(b1);
```

When on `debug="true"` the code works just fine. When turned to `false` it doesn't work. While debugging with IE8 the `if` statement is never reached and there are a bunch of errors.

It sounds like IE8 stops executing a JavaScript file when an error occurs and hence the code block is never reached. That is the only reason I can come up with as to why it works when `debug="true"` (files are loaded separately) and doesn't work when they are bundled (one single file).

Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: I ended up solving the problem by excluding jquery.check.js from the bundle and adding it as a separate reference. This basically proved my thinking was right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know you are right. Once an error occurs the script execution stops for that file.
If you really want to place them in the same file you could try to surround the jQuery declaration with a try/catch/finaly block (not sure it's a good ideea :| )

Also if you are using a .min.js file for production I believe you should not include that in the bundel.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use something like [modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) to do these tests for you?  That's what it's designed to do.  You can even have it [load the correct version of jQuery](https://gist.github.com/stugoo/5973965) for the browser.  Although a simpler choice would be to just use conditional comments.

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>  
  <script src="jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>  
<![endif]-->  
<!--[if (gte IE 9) | (!IE)]><!-->  
  <script src="jquery-2.0.0.js"></script>  
<!--<![endif]-->
```

I'm not sure why you would "not support" older browsers, since jQuery 1.9+ is feature compatible jQuery 2.x, you just have to load the right one for the right browser.

And why are you doing transforms.Clear()?  debug mode automatically removes minification..

Comment: At this moment the decision was not to support IE8 for two reasons: 1. IE8 users are a small percentage of our visitors and have been dropping fast and 2. the site was only tested with jQuery 2.0+. We do not have the time to retest it with IE8 and 1.9 yet. Furthermore I don't want to rely on browser specific conditions, checking for the presence of a function, property is a better way to go.

If you read the comments on the code posted, i'm intentionally removing the minification for debugging purposes. That line was removed after I figured out what was happening.

Comment: @JonasStawski - I hope that works out for you.  My experience is that invariably, some high value customer is found to be using IE8 and suddenly you're under the gun to make it work.  In any event, you can still use the jQuery version test.  And once again, jQuery 1.9+ and 2.0+ are functionally identical and tested by jQuery already.

Comment: thanks for the input. At this point of the game we need to move at a fast pace and that means leaving IE8 behind. I do agree that we might loose some important IE8 users and if it happens we will quickly find out and will need to start supporting it through one of your methods...

Comment: @JonasStawski - Actually, at this point, why not just use the conditional comments above and redirect to a "not supported" page if it's IE less than 9?  No jQuery checking necessary.

Comment: Because that is only IE 8 and below, it won't work for any other browser that is not supported by jQuery 2.0+